# How do I change the default path of IIS Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

Simply, how do I change the default path which IIS Express uses to write files too, etc.
It's currently set to C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express.
Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Code snippet:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"file1.txt", "Test!");
```

Comment: Can you add the snippet of code you are using to write and we will be able to provide you advice. You may get more help if you tag the language you are using also. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=netcore-2.2

```
 public static void Main()
    {
    // Create string for a directory. This value should be an existing directory
    // or the sample will throw a DirectoryNotFoundException.
      string dir = @"C:\test";      
      try
      {
          //Set the current directory.
          Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
      }
      catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("The specified directory does not exist. {0}", e);
      }
    // Print to console the results.
      Console.WriteLine("Root directory: {0}", Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(dir));
      Console.WriteLine("Current directory: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
}
```

Comment: That would work, but do you mean to say there is no way to change the settings of IIS Express without this?  Ah, and bonus question: what would be the relative directory of scripts when not running on IIS Express? Just their location in the project?